# Move block higher when the error is occured with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

So, this picture shows what I want, and below I am describing it in more detail:

[Link to the picture (I am not allowed to paste them here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kgki9.png)

So, I am explaining what is going . You have three main elements

1) the highest text "Bla bla bla bla"

2) the button "Click me"

3) and the lowest text

When you click the button, the error will occur, and it will be appeared, as you can see. I want to move two first elements higher, and I don't want the lowest text to be touched. So, it should stay in the same position as written.

My question is - How can I do it with HTML/CSS code (I don't ask about the JS code for text appearance). I need HTML/CSS will be in response to moving two first elements higher.

Comment: what do you mean by moving elements higher

Comment: @Ashishsah look at the image on the link. the error has display:none css code. When button is clicked, it changed to display:block, and this error need a space. So, the bottom text will be untouchable, but the two first elements will move higher to give a space for the error

Comment: @ashish watch the picture, and can you paste your css code or html code here? Or show us a picture of your codes?

Comment: I think this error could be fixed with flexbox

Comment: Start by showing us the HTML and CSS code you already have. Better still give us a [MCVE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be better handled with javascript as you could calculate the height of the error message display based off that. Anything else would probably be hacky and based off fixed heights as demonstrated below.

```js
//Purely to demonstrate CSS
$("#btn").click(function(){
  $(".msg").toggleClass("error");
});
```

```css
.msg {padding: 3em; border:1px solid black;}
.msg.error {padding-top: 1em; /*Remove the height of the error mesage*/
border-color:red;}

.errorMsg { 
display:none;
color:red;
height:2em;}

.error .errorMsg{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="msg">
<h1>bla blah bla</h1>
   <input type="button" value="Click Me" id="btn" />
   <div id="error" class="errorMsg">Error message goes here</div>
   <div>Text has to not move</div>
</div>
```

An alternate option is to use the [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) attribute to maintain the position of the hidden element on the page

```css
.msg {padding: 30px; border:1px solid black;}
.errorMsg { visibility:hidden; /*Important line*/
color:red;}

.errorMsg:target{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="msg">
<h1>bla blah bla</h1>
   <a href="#error">Click Me</a>
   <div id="error" class="errorMsg">Error message goes here</div>
   <div>Text has to not move</div>
</div>
```

I've used target in the above demo for styling, you can change this as required by adding a class to the error element or it's parent and style off that.

Comment: Great example, but the first two elements still not moving higher

Comment: Year, perfect. Thank you very much. I got it

Comment: No problem, don't forget to accept the answer (click the tick) and / or upvote (the up arrow)